# Fill the excel table based on a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list of items in excel, with the description and price for every one of them in the columns next to them. The example below:

```
Item 1    description 1   500
Item 2    description 2   6000
Item 3    description 3   35
Item 4    description 4   2500
```

The list consist of about 400 products. Now, what I would like to do is, based on this list, when I write Item name on the same sheet below to fill the next two columns with descritpion and price respectively. For example, when I write 'Item 1" in cell B501, I would like  excel to automtically fill C501 with 'description 1' and cell D501 with '500'

Is there a simple way to do this? Or will I need some kind of macro?

I am returning to excel after a while of not using it and need to refresh my memory :)

Comment: You're looking for VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine `IF` and `VLOOKUP` for this.

The `IF` statement will check to see if you have put a value in `B501` while the `VLOOKUP` will read the value in `B501` and display its corresponding cells from your values.

In cell C501 type this:

```
=IF(B501,VLOOKUP(B501,A1:C500,2,FALSE),"")
```

And in cell D501 type this:

```
=IF(B501,VLOOKUP(B501,A1:C500,3,FALSE),"")
```

This assumes your data is in cells `A1` to `C500`

You can then copy these formulas down as far as you need them.